# JVM argument to write system out stream to file

Tags: logging, java-8

I am working with mission critical applications. I would like to know what JVM argument I have to pass in order pump `out` and `err` stream into a file.

I have `log4j` as part of my application by using `slf4j` framework. Is there a way this can be achieved with `log4j`.

Comment: Did you check [Redirect System.out.println to log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403275/redirect-system-out-println-to-log) or [Want to make “System.out.println()” to print message to log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566960/want-to-make-system-out-println-to-print-message-to-log4j) already?

Comment: Its not `cron`, in fact some runs with Weblogic 12c.

Comment: If you have mission critical applications, why do they even write to `out` or `err`? where did you see `cron`... I didn't link or say anything about `cron`? But as you wrote something about Weblogic. May the following help you? [How to make WebLogic log all “console” message into a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112581/how-to-make-weblogic-log-all-console-message-into-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ...
      //Save default stdout and change stdout to be written to a buffer instead of console
      PrintStream defaultOut = System.out;
      ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = changeSystemOutputStream();
      try {
        //Do Stuff that would write to stdout
      }
      finally{
        //Change stdout back to default and write the log messages to file
        revertSystemOutputStream(buffer, defaultOut);
      }
    ...

    ByteArrayOutputStream changeSystemOutputStream(){
      ByteArrayOutputStream  buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(buffer));
      return buffer;
    }

    void revertSystemOutputStream(ByteArrayOutputStream buffer, PrintStream defaultOut ) {
      System.setOut(defaultOut);
      writeToFile(buffer.toString());
    }
```

Comment: This is only for stdout. do the same for err with System.setErr